# Can you mock an interface with a constructor with ts-mockito

Tags: typescript, testing, ts-mockito

First I am not married to `ts-mockito` it's just what we are using.

That being said we have an interface that has a constructor we would like to mock and inject into another class for testing. Is this possible with `ts-mockito`.

No matter what I try I end up with the output that the mock is `is not constructable`.

Here's an example code that can produce the error

```js
interface X {
  constructor(foo: string): any;
  bar: string;
}

const MockedX = mock<X>();
const mockedX1 = new MockedX();
```

Does anyone have any idea how to produce a mock on the fly?